# Custom filter with white space as thousands separator is not working

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers

I am trying to write a custom filter to filter numbers on the format `xxx xxx,xxx` in my application.

This is the function I wrote so far:

```
var formatNumber = function(input, fractionSeparator, thousandsSeparator, fractionSize) {
    fractionSeparator = fractionSeparator || ',';
    thousandsSeparator = thousandsSeparator || ' ';
    fractionSize = fractionSize || 3;     
    var output = '', parts = [];

    input = input.toString();
    parts = input.split(".");
    output = parts[0].replace(/(\d{3})/g, ""+ thousandsSeparator +"$1").trim();
    if(parts.length>1){
        output += fractionSeparator;
        output += parts[1].substring(0, fractionSize);
    }       
    return output;
};
```

Actually this function works perfectly for some numbers but fails in other cases, for example:

**Works with the following numbers:**

- For `451.585478` it prints `451,585`.
- For `154455451.58` it prints `154 455 451,58`.

**Fails for these examples:**

- For `54455451.58` it prints `54455 451,58`.
- For `55451.58` it prints `55451,58`.

**Demo:**

```js
var formatNumber = function(input, fractionSeparator, thousandsSeparator, fractionSize) {
  fractionSeparator = fractionSeparator || ',';
  thousandsSeparator = thousandsSeparator || ' ';
  fractionSize = fractionSize || 3;
  var output = '',
    parts = [];

  input = input.toString();
  parts = input.split(".");
  output = parts[0].replace(/(\d{3})/g, "" + thousandsSeparator + "$1").trim();
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    output += fractionSeparator;
    output += parts[1].substring(0, fractionSize);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(formatNumber(154455451.58));

console.log(formatNumber(55451.58));
console.log(formatNumber(54455451.58));
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. Any help will be appreciated.

---

## Edit:

I finally got it working, the problem was with my Regex, this is the final regex I used to format thousands in my number:

```
output = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandsSeparator).trim();
```

This the final code:

```js
var formatNumber = function(input, fractionSeparator, thousandsSeparator, fractionSize) {

  fractionSeparator = fractionSeparator || ',';
  thousandsSeparator = thousandsSeparator || ' ';
  fractionSize = fractionSize || 3;
  var output = '',
    parts = [];

  input = input.toString();
  parts = input.split(".");
  output = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandsSeparator).trim();
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    output += fractionSeparator;
    output += parts[1].substring(0, fractionSize);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(formatNumber(154455451.58));

console.log(formatNumber(55451.58));
console.log(formatNumber(54455451.58));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you for pointing it out, the problem was in my regex. I used the one in the other answer and combined it with my code and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
output = parts[0].replace(/(\d{3})/g, ""+ thousandsSeparator +"$1").trim();
```

You are inserting the space before every 3 digits (I'll mark matches between brackets):

```
"(123)(456)78" --> "( 123)( 456)78"
```

Then you are trimming it --> `"123 45678"`

Your idea is nice, but you must do it starting from right to left so I will invert `parts[0]` and the replacement:

```
parts[0] = parts[0].split('').reverse().join('');
"12345678" --> "87654321"

parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1" + thousandsSeparator).trim();
"(876)(543)21" --> "(876 )(543 )21"

output = parts[0].split('').reverse().join('');
"876 543 21" --> "12 345 678"
```

Which is the output you want. Here is the updated snippet:

```js
var formatNumber = function(input, fractionSeparator, thousandsSeparator, fractionSize) {
  fractionSeparator = fractionSeparator || ',';
  thousandsSeparator = thousandsSeparator || ' ';
  fractionSize = fractionSize || 3;
  var output = '',
    parts = [];

  input = input.toString();
  parts = input.split(".");
  
  parts[0] = parts[0].split('').reverse().join('');
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1" + thousandsSeparator).trim();
  output = parts[0].split('').reverse().join('');
  
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    output += fractionSeparator;
    output += parts[1].substring(0, fractionSize);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(formatNumber(154455451.58));

console.log(formatNumber(55451.58));
console.log(formatNumber(54455451.58));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried to implement it with a reverse solution, but I was using the wrong regex. Well pointed out.

Comment: I finally used this regex to get it working, `output = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandsSeparator).trim();`. But thank you for the fix you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your number on `.` and then split it and convert it to an array and can use `array#map` and `array#filter` to get a new array with its element grouped in chunk of 3 and then you just have to `reverse` and `join` it backl

```js
const formatNumber = (num, fractionSeparator, thousandsSeparator, fractionSize) => {
  fractionSeparator = fractionSeparator || ',';
  thousandsSeparator = thousandsSeparator || ' ';
  fractionSize = fractionSize || 3;
  let [first, second] = num.toString().split('.');
  let reversed = first.split('').reverse();
  reversed = reversed.map((e,i) => i%fractionSize===0 ? reversed.slice(i,i+fractionSize).join('') :null)
          .filter(x => x)
          .reverse()
          .join(thousandsSeparator);
  return reversed + fractionSeparator + second;
}

console.log(formatNumber(154455451.58));
console.log(formatNumber(55451.58));
console.log(formatNumber(54455451.58));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's a nice approach as well, but the problem was with the regex I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that is based off of a "currency formatter" method that I once wrote:

```
var sRegexFormatPattern = '^([^\\' + thousandsSeparator +
                          '\.]+)(\\d{3}[\\' + thousandsSeparator +
                          '\.]|\\d{3}$)';
var regexFormatPattern = new RegExp(sRegexFormatPattern);

while (regexFormatPattern.test(input)) {
    input = input.replace(regexFormatPattern, '$1' + thousandsSeparator + '$2');
}
```

Let's break down that regex starting from back to front . . .

- The second capture group (`(\\d{3}[\\' + thousandsSeparator + '\.]|\\d{3}$)`) matches exactly 3 digits and a either a decimal point (`\d{3}\.`), the character passed in as the "thousandsSeparator" (`\d{3}\THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR`), or the end of the string (`\d{3}$`).
- The first capture group (`^([^\\' + thousandsSeparator + '\.]+)`) matches all characters (which **should** all be digits . . . you'd need a separate check to make sure of that) that aren't either a decimal point or the character passed in as the "thousandsSeparator", **up until it hits the second capture group**.

**NOTE:** I added in an escape slash before the "thousandsSeparator", just in case somebody typed in something that has another meaning in regex, but, even still, some characters could cause issues in the execution of the regex . . . would need to look into it more to make it foolproof.

As long as it can find those two pieces inside the value, it will break them up with the "thousandsSeparator" and check again.  Using "12345678.90" as an example, the iterations go like this:

- `12345` `678.` --- changes the number to ---> 12345 678.90
- `12` `345 678.` --- changes the number to ---> 12 345 678.90

Everything before and after that section is more-or-less what you already had . . . I added a minor tweak to how you formatted the "fraction" part of the string as well, but the rest is pretty much the same (*see full JS code below*).

Using your test values, I got:

```
- 451.585478 --->           451,585
- 154455451.58 ---> 154 455 451,58
- 54455451.58 --->   54 455 451,58
- 55451.58 --->          55 451,58
```

---

**DEMO**

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".formattingInput").on("change", function() {
    $("#formattedNumber").text(formatNumber(
      $("#unformattedNumberInput").val(),
      $("#fractionSeparator").val(),
      $("#thousandsSeparator").val(),
      $("#fractionSize").val()
    ));
  });
});

var formatNumber = function(input, fractionSeparator, thousandsSeparator, fractionSize) {
  fractionSeparator = fractionSeparator || ',';
  thousandsSeparator = thousandsSeparator || ' ';
  fractionSize = fractionSize || 3;

  var sRegexFormatPattern = '^([^\\' + thousandsSeparator +
    '\.]+)(\\d{3}[\\' + thousandsSeparator +
    '\.]|\\d{3}$)';
  var regexFormatPattern = new RegExp(sRegexFormatPattern);

  while (regexFormatPattern.test(input)) {
    input = input.replace(regexFormatPattern, '$1' + thousandsSeparator + '$2');
  }

  var parts = input.split('.');

  if (parts.length > 1) {
    input = parts[0] +
      fractionSeparator +
      parts[1].substring(0, fractionSize);
  }

  return (input.length > 0) ? input : 'Please input a value in the "Number" field.';
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="unformattedNumberInput">Number: <input type="text" id="unformattedNumberInput" class="formattingInput" /></label><br />
  <label for="thousandsSeparator">Thousands Separator: <input type="text" id="thousandsSeparator" class="formattingInput" /></label><br />
  <label for="fractionSeparator">Fraction Separator: <input type="text" id="fractionSeparator" class="formattingInput" /></label><br />
  <label for="fractionSize">Fraction Size: <input type="text" id="fractionSize" class="formattingInput" /></label><br /><br />
</div>

<div>
  <strong>Result:</strong>
  <span id="formattedNumber">Please input a value in the "Number" field.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It seems to be a good solution too, but a Demo would be appreciated.

Comment: @chsdk - Done.   :)