# thousand and decimal separate in key up event

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, keyup

I used below code to thousand and decimal separate in key up event. But after entering 15 digits value gets 0. what will be the reason ??

```js
<script>
var myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');

myinput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var val = this.value;
  val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
  
  if(val != "") {
    valArr = val.split('.');
    valArr[0] = (parseInt(valArr[0],10)).toLocaleString();
    val = valArr.join('.');
  }
  
  this.value = val;
});

</script>
```

```html
<input id="myinput" type="text'>
```

Comment: See [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Comment: @Nit Thanks & understood. any solution for this ??

Comment: Well that really depends on what you want to do with the value. If you just need the value and don't care about the type, do all the operations in string form and don't parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem here is that you reached the maximum possible value for `Number` on `parseInt()` when it tries to parse the input `string` value, check the [**Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER** MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) for further details.

So all the extra digits you enter, when the number exceeds the [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), will be ignored and transformed to 0. Please check [**Working with large integers in JavaScript** tutorial](http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html) for more explanation and examples.

So, you can't treat a large `number` value as a `Number` in Javsacript because there's a Maximum possible value limit, you need to treat it as a `string`, so it can exceed this max `value`.

**Solution:**

The solution here is to treat this `number` as a `string` and use `Regex` and `.replace()` method to change its format.

Here's [**a solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47039134/3669624) that I wrote before and that I always use to format numbers, it will solve your problem:

```
var formatNumber = function(input, fractionSeparator, thousandsSeparator, fractionSize) {

  fractionSeparator = fractionSeparator || '.';
  thousandsSeparator = thousandsSeparator || ',';
  fractionSize = fractionSize || 3;
  var output = '',
    parts = [];

  input = input.toString();
  parts = input.split(".");
  output = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandsSeparator).trim();
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    output += fractionSeparator;
    output += parts[1].substring(0, fractionSize);
  }
  return output;
};
```

**Demo:**

This is a working [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/4922825z/) with your original code.

Comment: thanks & understood! any solution for this? I don't care about the type

Comment: @sampath Chek my Edit, I shared a solution using `Regex` and `string.replace()`.

Comment: It works. up voted. I don't know what is the reason to down vote.

Comment: @sampath Me too, I think it was a downvote before the Edit as it doesn't show a solution.